# Release chain in Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have A, B and C maven projects in different git repositories. C is depend on A and B. I have Jenkins jobs, which build the projects individually. But I would like to make a chain for release. Eg: After project A has been released, change the dependency version in project C and commit it to the repo, than trigger a new release for project C as well. 
If projekt B is released than do the same. Update project C, commit, and release.
Do you know plugin for Jenkins, which makes this update dependency version and commit to git?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of constraint 4 or 5 years ago. Often I had about 10 projects to release. I did not have the same repository constraint but I coudn't use multi-modules for these projects.

I end up building a "release pipeline or orchestrator" in Java.

In a configuration file, I was specifying for each project the expected release version number and the next build version number. 
The idea was if the project release was not existing in Nexus, I was releasing the project and updating the dependencies version number (using properties).

This project was also packaging, in a zip file, a bunch of things that were delivered then to the QA Team (using assembly maven plugin).

In my next job assignments, I did not have the same kind of needs. 
If there is a plugin that is doing the job now, I will be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) is exactly what you are looking for. It provides a new job type and a DSL where you can configure when/how other jobs are triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I do suggest to use multiple plugins. Each has its own strengths:

- [Job DSL Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/) to specify a simple chain of jobs. Do not add much logic to it plus the ocassional fork/join of downstream jobs.
- [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for those complex build flows. Groovy is greate for defining complex steps.
- [Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) plus [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) to display an continous integration/delivery pipeline. It allows you to aggregate downstream/upstream jobs very cleanly.

[Read this post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/04/generated-jenkins-jobs-and-automatic-branch-merging-for-feature-branches/) for a concrete demonstration on how powerful **Job DSL Plugin** really is. It enlightened me! :)
[image: Examply of Delivery Pipeline]

As [@Jcs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323054/156042) suggested, you could also use [Build FlowDSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) but it is not very stable and some *core* functionality is only available for **Cloudbees Entrerprise** users.